# Rollback and return instance with error instead of nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I'm new to Ruby/RoR.
This is `services/create_subscription.rb`.
(I add service class, because I wanted to encapslate the logic.)

I'd like to rollback and out put the errors of subscription within Controller.
The problem here is that Rollback does work, but returns `nil`.
This should return `subscription.errors[:base] << e.message` and rollback if API calling failed somehow.

Any ideas to refactor the code?

```
    class CreateSubscription
      def self.call(course, email_address)
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        user = CreateUser.call(email_address)

        subscription = Subscription.new(
          course: course,
          user: user
        )

        begin
          book_sub = nil
          if user.book_customer_id.blank?
            customer = Book::Customer.create(
              email: user.email,
              course: course.book_id,
            )
            user.customer_id = customer.id
            user.save!
            book_sub = customer.books.first
          else
            customer = Book::Customer.retrieve(user.book_customer_id)
            book_sub = customer.books.create(
              course: course.book_id
            )
          end

          subscription.book_id = book_sub.id

          subscription.save!
        rescue Book::BookError => e
          subscription.errors[:base] << e.message
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end

        subscription
      end 
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need

```
raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
```

in the rescue block, because Rails rollbacks transaction when exception occurs in the transaction block.So you should remove this line.

And as the exception by ActiveRecord::Rollback is not catched by outside of 
block, I guess your transaction block aren't aware of that exception.

So, try put the transaction block inside of the begin block, to catch exception outside of transaction block.